# WebAPI - works local but receive 404 error on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This works...

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/InventoryApi/");
```

This fails...

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yyyZLtd.com/");
```

Remote server running IIS 8.5 on Win Server 2012 R2

Full code...

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/InventoryApi/");
```

or

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yyyZLtd.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Inventory/99");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) <- ERROR RETURNED
```

Full error message...

> {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Date: Mon, 02 May 2016 14:54:08 GMT
>     Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     Content-Length: 1245
>     Content-Type: text/html
>   }}

I must be missing something. New at Web Api, have always used SOAP which seems a lot easier.

Thanks and any help appreciated.

Comment: How about `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yyyZLtd.com/InventoryApi/");`?

Comment: Darin... tried that as well. Same error message.

Comment: Where is the api for the controller?

Comment: I doubt your error has anything to do with Web Api vs SOAP and everything to do with the IIS or ASP.NET setup.

Comment: So you are going to InventoryApi on localhost, but api/inventory on your prod server??

Comment: t0mm13b... I don't understand your question. Isn't the controller in the same place whether local or remote?

Comment: how you've configured routing for webapi i mean the path is /InventoryApi in localhost but on prod the url is http://yyyZLtd.com [no path] ?

Comment: InventoryApi is the website on local IIS. yyyZLtd.com is the website on the remote server.

Comment: The routing for Get is [Route("api/Inventory/{Key}")] where Key=99 ... so wouldn't the full be http://yyyZLtd.com/api/Inventory/99

Comment: Can you access the remote server via another client, e.g. a web browser or a HTTP client like Postman?

Comment: With Postman, i get the foillowing error...

405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

http://yyyZLtd.com/api/inventory/99

Comment: Still looking for a solution... I moved the source to the server and rebuilt using VS2015.  Now I get a 404 error using either localhost or a domain. I think the issue must be in one of the settings in IIS... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just when I was ready to quit... I tried this before without success, but this time it worked...

Drew.... Thanks for the suggestion.

I started totally over - Success was on the 4th attempt. Initially, I was trying to create a WebApi project from the empty template and only adding WebApi. I finally decided to use the empty template using both Mvc and WebApi and a target framework of 4.6. I added the same classes and controller as used before and it worked, at least on to Get or Post. The modules change above, gave me the ability of Put and Delete.

I made the following changes were made to my Web.Config...

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV"/>      
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
```

Hope this helps some one else. I played with this on and off for 4 days before getting everything to work. More than happy to share the code if anyone wants.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? This *really* doesn't help anyone who may experience the same problem as you in the future.

Comment: Yes, I too have the same problem and this answer does not help me.